# Comparing 2 Dictionary<string, string> Instances

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, comparison

I want to compare the contents of two `Dictionary<string, string>` instances regardless of the order of the items they contain.  `SequenceEquals` also compares the order, so I first order the dictionaries by key and then call `SequenceEquals`.

Is there a method that I can use instead of `SequenceEquals` that will only compare the contents?

If there isn't, is this the ideal way to do this?

```
Dictionary<string, string> source = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> target = new Dictionary<string, string>();

source["foo"] = "bar";
source["baz"] = "zed";
source["blah"] = null;

target["baz"] = "zed";
target["blah"] = null;
target["foo"] = "bar";

// sequenceEquals will be false
var sequenceEqual = source.SequenceEqual(target);
// contentsEqual will be true
var contentsEqual = source.OrderBy(x => x.Key).SequenceEqual(target.OrderBy(x => x.Key));
```

Comment: The question contains a very big flaw. There is no such thing as an order in which elements are in a dictionary. By definition, a dictionary holds key to value pairs without any implicit ordering.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
var contentsEqual = source.DictionaryEqual(target);

// ...

public static bool DictionaryEqual<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> first, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> second)
{
    return first.DictionaryEqual(second, null);
}

public static bool DictionaryEqual<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> first, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> second,
    IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueComparer)
{
    if (first == second) return true;
    if ((first == null) || (second == null)) return false;
    if (first.Count != second.Count) return false;

    valueComparer = valueComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;

    foreach (var kvp in first)
    {
        TValue secondValue;
        if (!second.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out secondValue)) return false;
        if (!valueComparer.Equals(kvp.Value, secondValue)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: By having unordered dictionaries, your algorithm runs in O(n^2).

Comment: @Yuriy: How is it O(n^2), assuming that the hashcodes are half-decent?

Comment: Assuming GetHash was implemented.

Comment: I'll concede, I didn't know GetHashCode implementation on Object returned real hash codes.

Comment: @Yuriy: If you're using dictionaries then you *either* assume that the hashcodes are half-decent, *or* you make sure that they are. A key lookup in a dictionary is assumed to be roughly O(1). If it's not then you're going to see poor performance all-round, not just in my method.

Comment: Should this work for dictionaries of any type? I'm using a `Dictionary<string, string[]>` and it's always returning false even though all the values match.

Comment: @sab669: Yes, it should work for dictionaries of any type. I suspect that your `string[]` values are treated as unequal because arrays default to reference comparison rather than a comparison of the array contents. You'll need to pass in an `EqualityComparer<>` that compares the contents of the arrays.

Comment: It's an useful extension,there is a suggest for that the method also need `IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer`

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there is an existing method but you could use the following (null checking of args omitted for brevity)

```
public static bool DictionaryEquals<TKey,TValue>(
  this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> left,
  Dictionary<TKey,TValue> right ) { 

  var comp = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
  if ( left.Count != right.Count ) { 
    return false;
  }
  foreach ( var pair in left ) {
    TValue value;
    if ( !right.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out value) 
         || !comp.Equals(pair.Value, value) ) {
      return false;
    }
  } 
  return true;
}
```

It would be best to add an overload to allow customization of the `EqualityComparer<TValue>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) you won't need to apply the sorting yourself, which can be slightly easier to use:

```
void Main()
{
    var d1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["a"] = "Hi there!",
        ["b"] = "asd",
        ["c"] = "def"
    };
    var d2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["b"] = "asd",
        ["a"] = "Hi there!",
        ["c"] = "def"
    };

    var sortedDictionary1 = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(d1);
    var sortedDictionary2 = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(d2);

    if (sortedDictionary1.SequenceEqual(sortedDictionary2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not match!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This will check if all `Values` from `source` exists in `target`, ignoring the `Keys`

```
var result = source.All(x => target.Any(y => x.Value == y.Value));
```

Comment: This misses the case where `target` has additional key value pairs not in `source`

Comment: @JaredPar: If `target` has additional pairs then what should happen? Return `false` instead of `true`? Then an additional check for length would fix it right?

Comment: I would say if the contents are different then they are not equal.  A length check would fix the `target` is bigger but not the issue of keys being different.

Comment: @JaredPar: I assume the OP want to compare just the contents. `[...] that will only compare the contents?`