# How to Compare Values of Two Dictionary and Increment Count if DictA key,values Exists in DictB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, compare, match

I have Two Dictionary DictA & DictB such as:

```
Dictionary<int, string> DictA = new Dictionary<int, string>();
DicA.add(1,"Mango");
DicA.add(2,"Grapes");
DicA.add(3,"Orange");

Dictionary<int, string> DictB = new Dictionary<int, string>();
DicB.add(1,"Mango");
DicB.add(2,"Pineapple");
```

How to Compare the values of these Two Dictionary **DictA key,value** with **DictB key,value** and if **MATCH IS FOUND** then *INCREMENT the COUNTER* variable.

Note: DicA may Contains many Rows as compared to DicB
EG: DicA has 3 Rows and DicB has 2 Rows. If DicA key,value match(similar/equal) to DicB key,val then increment the counter variable by one!

Any Suggestion..! Help Appreciated...!

Comment: What does "match is found" mean? Same key maps to same value?

Comment: value of DIctA matches value of DictB

Comment: Where is the counter variable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928822/comparing-2-dictionarystring-string-instances

Comment: Sorry @Jon for incomplete information...nw have edited...! plz Reply...!

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE: "similar/equal" is still not good enough. What do you consider "similar"?

Comment: objects in dict could be reference types in that case equal and similar are two different things.

Comment: Dear @Jon..! i mean to say EXACT EQUAL key,Value pairs...!
Posted with Example...! @Adam Solved my problem...! Thanks to u too....! I Dont know why people are EAGER to DOWN VOTE...?

Comment: The code in your post will not work. You are creating a dictionary `DictA` but adding keys/values to `DicA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
Dictionary<int, string> DicA = new Dictionary<int, string>();
DicA.Add(1,"Mango");
DicA.Add(2,"Grapes");
DicA.Add(3,"Orange");

Dictionary<int, string> DicB = new Dictionary<int, string>();
DicB.Add(1,"Mango");
DicB.Add(2,"Pineapple");

int counter = 0;

foreach (var pair in DicA)
{
     string value;

     if (DicB.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out value))
     {
          if (value == pair.Value)
          {
                counter++;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: It compiles fine for me, i'm guessing you just cut and pasted it without checking variable names... But yes @SamLeach, value should be a string.

Comment: just i want to inform you that it gives error dont misunderstand..!

Comment: What specific error does it throw? I ran this exact code on my machine and the value of `counter` returns `1` as expected.

Comment: you have edited your code ur previous code is:
 foreach (var pair in DictA)
        {
            int value;
            if (DictB.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out value))
            {
                if (value == pair.Value)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Yes, I know. @SamLeach kindly pointed out that `value` should be a string.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
int matches = DictA.Keys.Where(k => DictB.ContainsKey(k) && DictB[k] == DictA[k]).Count();
```