# Checking all entries from one Dictionary are in another Dictionary

Tags: c#, compare

i have two Dictionarys A & B, i want to see if all entries in A exist in B. In the past i've compared Lists using the following:

```
var set1 = new HashSet<String>(list1);
var set2 = new HashSet<String>(list2);

return set1.SetEquals(set2);
```

What i have thought to do is simply loop over each value in Dictionary A using:

```
dictA.TryGetValue(dictBvalue, out item)
```

this will return null on the item var if the value isn't there, but this seems a little long winded.

Is there a quick and effcient way of comparing dictionaries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `All` extension and do this.

```
var allexist = list1.All(x=> list2.ContainsKey(x.Key) && list2[x.Key] == x.Value)
```

Comment: Typo, it shuold be `x` :-)

Comment: this does what i need quickly and effciently, thanks :)

Comment: Just to clarify, if all items in list1 are in list2 then this returns true, if any of the items in list1 do not occur in list2 then it returns false?

Comment: Thank you :) Just one more question for you, is there anyway to output the keys from list1 that were not found in list2 to a new list using the same simple approach as above?

Comment: use this `list1.Keys.Where(k=>!list2.ContainsKey(k)).ToList()` this returns keys in list1 which are not there in list2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107838/discussion-between-dan-hall-and-hari-prasad).

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution if you want to  loop over each value

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictA = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> dictB = new Dictionary<string, string>();
bool allexist = true;

foreach (var itemA in dictA)
{
    if (!dictB.ContainsKey(itemA.Key))
    {
        allexist = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are **lots** of optimizations possible, compare it with [DictionaryEquals method from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928822/comparing-2-dictionarystring-string-instances/3928856#3928856)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you asked for a method comparing dictionaries but your code example refer to HashSet which is different.

For HashSets, you can use [IsSubsetOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SetEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

To compare dictionaries, you can use [DictionaryEquals method from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3928856/540761)

Comment: That was just an example of what i would do with lists, in this case i'm looking for a similar solution for dictionaries. I'll check that link, thanks.